# jquery - What is the simplest way to merge url params?

Tags: jquery, uri

For some reason I have an iframe on my page:

```
<iframe src="/widget?id=2"/>
```

And I have variable **address** in my js code.

```
var address = 'some street';
```

I need to add a new parameter to iframe src attribute, so that it looks like:

```
<iframe src="/widget?id=2&address=some%20street"/>
```

I wish:

- not to bother what the format of **address** variable is: it can contain not only spaces, but also comas, semicolons and so on (*somehow inserted by a user*);
- not to make ugly string manipulations, that are always hard to read;
- to be able to deal with more than one parameter (*not only address*) in
  a more elegant way.

For example merging **url** params in **Ruby on Rails** is as easy as:

```
params.merge {:address => address}
```

I want something like this in jQuery if it is posible.

Answer (score 0):

My current (rough and fast) implementation is:

```
var src = $('iframe').attr('src');
var new_src = src.replace(/([?&])address=[^$&]*/,'$1address='+encodeURI(address));;
if (src == new_src) new_src = src+'&address='+encodeURI(address);
$('iframe').attr('src',new_src);
```

Comment: What if you have a `street_address` in your query string?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you.

The parameter I'm going to change is **address**, users can only change it's value, not its name.

Comment: Your regex will replace the value of `street_address` as well. Personally, I would just parse the URL parameters into an object, modify that, and turn it back into a query string.

Comment: Yep, thanx, that's a mistake. Can you answer my question adding some code examples?